# Prove that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous for any $x \in (0, \infty)$.

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

A problem from my analysis homework:

Prove directly that the function $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

I think I have the details worked out; I would just like to check that I have the ideas correct.

Proof: Let $ x_0 \in (0, \infty) $ be arbitrary and fix $ \epsilon >0 $. Notice that 
$$ \left|\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x_0^2}\right| \le \frac{(|x| + |x_0|)|x-x_0|}{x^2x_0^2} $$

Let $ \delta = \epsilon\frac{x_0^3}{6} $. Thus if $ |x-x_0| < \delta $, we have $$ \left|\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x_0^2}\right| \le \frac{(|x| + |x_0|)|x-x_0|}{x^2x_0^2} < \delta\frac{(|x| + |x_0|)}{x^2x_0^2}<\delta\frac{6}{x_0^3} = \epsilon \quad\square$$

The key part of this proof was the construction of $\delta$, for which I required that $|x| < \frac{x_0}{2}$. Doing so allowed me to say $\frac{(|x| + |x_0|)}{x^2x_0^2} < \frac{6}{x_0^3} $. The part I am unsure about is how we can make this requirement (if it is correct; if not, why not and what is a more justifiable condition?). I know that we are trying to "control" the value of $x$ by making it "close-enough" to $x_0$ but the $\frac{x_0}{2}$ part seems arbitrary. Couldn't we just as easily require $|x| < \frac{x_0}{3}$?

Comment: You will need to modify the construction slightly.  Suppose that some joker gives you $\epsilon=500$. Then the interval you constructed may very well even include $x=0$. You will have to use something like $\delta=\min(x_0/2,w)$ where $w$ is  the $\delta$ of your answer.

Comment: How could the interval include $x=0$ if $x \in (0, \infty)$?

Comment: Furthermore, could you please clarify the need for $\frac{x_0}{2}$? Do we have control over $x$? That is, since we are proving "$\textit{if}\,$ $x$ is close enough to $x_0$, then blah blah blah", are we allowed to control the value of $x$?

Comment: If for example $x_0=1$ and you conclude that everything is OK if $|x-x_0|\lt 50$, a mistake has been made. For the last comment, we **must** control $x$, that's precisely the point of constructing a suitable $\delta$.  We don't need to insist that $\delta\lt x_0/2$, even $\lt 0.99x_0$ would be good enough. Or we can be more restrictive and ask that $\delta\lt x_0/100$. Plus of course the condition related to $\epsilon$.

Comment: Why is not that we require $|x| < \delta$ but that $|x|< \frac{x_0}{2}$. Isn't $\delta$ the tool we use to control $x$? It seems a bit strange to me do this round-about thing where we make a restriction on $x$ then build a $\delta$ out of that restriction rather than restricting $x$ using $\delta$ in the first place.

Comment: We require $|x-x_0|\lt \delta$. And we need to control the range of movement of $x$. Maybe if no one does for a few hours I will write out a solution. I hesitate, since the question is a relative to several questions I have written solutions to.

Answer (score 0):

the $\frac{x_0}2$ is required for proving continuity from below.

it is worth noting that continuity from above is somewhat easier to show because (for $\delta \gt 0$):
$$
\frac1{x_0^2} - \frac1{(x_0+\delta)^2} = \frac{\delta^2+2\delta x_0}{x_0^2(x_0+\delta)^2} \lt \frac{2\delta^2+2\delta x_0}{x_0^2(x_0+\delta)^2}\lt \frac{2\delta}{x_0^2(x_0+\delta)} \lt \frac{2\delta}{x_0^3}
$$
for continuity from below we have:
$$
\frac1{(x_0-\delta)^2}-\frac1{x_0^2}= \frac{2\delta x_0-\delta^2}{x_0^2(x_0-\delta)^2}
$$
the simplification now requires $\delta \lt \frac{x_0}2$, in which case we have
$$
\frac{2\delta x_0-\delta^2}{x_0^2(x_0-\delta)^2} \lt \frac{2\delta x_0}{x_0^2(x_0-\delta)^2} \lt \frac{2\delta x_0}{x_0^2(\frac{x_0}2)^2}=\frac{8\delta}{x_0^3}
$$